# Is there a way to combine discontinuous capture groups in a single regex?

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I am using C++ RE2. I want to save concatenated discontinuous capture groups in result string.
The Regex itself may have one or more capture groups.

```
RE2::PartialMatch(sourceStr, Regex, &result)
```

**Example**

```
sourceStr = "This is an example."
Regex = "(This).*(example)"
result = "Thisexample"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
string result = sourceStr;
RE2::Replace(&result, "(This).*(example)", "$1$2");
```

Comment: the $ sign does not work. it replaces it with literal $1$2, how can I capture the matching groups? is the syntax correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why use an outside library when you have the  library already existing in the studio itself. Use it with the "match function.
A link to refer for further learning: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex